# Promises and mocha

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, mocha.js

I'm trying to test some of my async code. But I'm having some trouble.

I'v read this (https://github.com/wietsevenema/testing-aync-with-mocha/blob/master/test.js), and tried all examples. But I still get Timeout Error (with my own Promise implementation with mongoose).

Starting to think that there is something wrong in my code, see below.

```
static updateEndDate(userId: string, endDate: Date):Promise<iUserModel> {
    return UserSchema.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': userId}, {$set: {exp_on: endDate}})
        .exec()
        .then((user: iUserModel) => {
            if(user)
                return Promise.resolve(user);
            else
                return Promise.reject({errmsg: 'No user found'});
        }).catch(e => {
            return Promise.reject(e);
        })
}
```

When I try the below code:

```
const resolvingPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  resolve('promise resolved')
);

    it('assertion success', async () => {
      const result = await resolvingPromise;
      chai.expect(result).to.equal('promise resolved');
    });
```

Everything works out. But when I use my own implementation, I get the timeout.

```
   it('assertion success', async () => {
      const result = await User.findByID('41224d776a326fb40f000001');
      chai.expect(result).to.equal('testing');
    });
```

Just want to add I've tried this implementation also:

```
it('assertion success', async () => {
  return User.findByID('41224d776a326fb40f000001')
  .then((res) => {
    chai.expect(res).to.equal('test');
  });
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You should not use done when using promises?

https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: @gelv You show a function named `updateEndDate` but in your example tests you use `User.findByID`. What's the relation between the two?

Comment: Be sure you are specifying a promise library like `mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise;` or `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` and try  `const result = await User.findByID('41224d776a326fb40f000001').exec();`

Comment: Also I think your code can be improved. `.catch(e => { return Promise.reject(e); })` you don't need this, catching a rejected promise just to return a new promise with same rejection reason.

Comment: And whatever you return from `onFulfilled` callback will be wrapped into a promise. https://promisesaplus.com/  `if(user) return Promise.resolve(user); else return Promise.reject({errmsg: 'No user found'});` can be written `if(user) return user; else throw new Error('No user found');`

Comment: Are you sure you're not forgetting the `.exec()` call? I'm not familiar with the mongoose implementation, but [in the doc I see that with `exec` it does provide a full fledged Promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html). Without it only provides a `then` function.